# Upgrading to Ruby 3.1 causes Psych::DisallowedClass exception when using YAML.load_file

Tags: ruby, yaml, activesupport

When upgrading to ruby 3.1, I am seeing the following sort error message when using `YAML.load_file some_file_name`

```
 Psych::DisallowedClass:
   Tried to load unspecified class: Matrix
```

Other load statements cause similar errors but cite different unspecified classes e.g. OpenStruct.  It appears that the latest version of YAML only loads classes from a permitted white list, so it is necessary to use a permitted_class keyword to allow other classes. I have tried

```
hsh = YAML.load_file some_file_name, permitted_classes: [Matrix, OpenStruct]
```

but this gives the error

```
 Psych::DisallowedClass:
   Tried to load unspecified class: Symbol
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Symbol` is also not allowed per default when loading YAML in Ruby. Therefore, you need to add `Symbol` to the `permitted_classes` in your case too when reading the YAML file:

```
hash = YAML.load_file(
  some_file_name, 
  permitted_classes: [Matrix, OpenStruct, Symbol]
)
```

See the list of default [`permitted_classes`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-safe_load) in Psych (the YAML parser used by Ruby).

**Or**, when using in Ruby on Rails, you can configure globally in your `config/application.rb` what classes your Ruby on Rails application should allow as permitted classes when reading a YAML files:

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes += [Matrix, OpenStruct, Symbol]
```

Note that for internal YAML parsing in Ruby on Rails `Symbol` is already the default for [`active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cc359c077fadc619dd4d098a3639b6eab22d6a06/activerecord/lib/active_record.rb#L441).

Answer (score 41):

The working solution is to add this line to config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess]
```

You can do the same with any class name, like

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Hash, Array, ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess]
```

Answer (score 19):

Had this on rails 6.1 upgrade. If you have no other choice, maybe this workaround will bring you some time (application.rb):

```rb
config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load = true
```

Comment: Full details explaining the change, including other workarounds, are here: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/cve-2022-32224-possible-rce-escalation-bug-with-serialized-columns-in-active-record/81017

Comment: worked for me...24-09-2022

Answer (score 1):

When using the `YAML.load_file` directly, the `config.yaml_column_permitted_classes` is not used. That is only used, when Rails loads YAML (config files, serialized YAML).

You can:

- a.) either, pass the list of allowed classes to the `YAML.load_file(path, permitted_classes: [..])` like @spickermann has written, or:
- b.) You can switch to `YAML.unsafe_load_file` (e.g. for Test cases).

Answer (score 0):

The “safe YAML” loading method does not allow all classes to be deserialized by default. This option allows you to specify classes deemed “safe” in your application. For example, if your application uses Symbol and Time in serialized data, you can add Symbol and Time to the allowed list.

Fixed by adding this to application.rb:

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date, Time]
```

Comment: I tried this, both in config/application.rb and each environment config and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Rails configuration to use YAML/Psych's unsafe_load (see Mohamed's & crazywulf's answer). I needed to change this config without restarting the Rails app, so I did this:

```rb
ActiveRecord.use_yaml_unsafe_load = true
```

Please mind, this is just a temporary fix for the current process. It will be gone as soon as you restart the server.