# Tried to load unspecified class: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone - Psych::DisallowedClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, activesupport

Does anyone know how to fix this exception? Not sure if it's related but it is falling on `#discard` method calling from `discard` gem.

```ruby
if object.discard
   # Psych::DisallowedClass:
   #   Tried to load unspecified class: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

I've tried each of the following config settings added to config/application.rb but the issue still persists(no spring running, no preloading)

```
# config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Hash, Array, ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, Time]
# config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load
# config.active_support.use_yaml_unsafe_load
```

Ruby version: 3.1.2 |
Rails version: 6.1.7

Related question:

[Upgrading to Ruby 3.1 causes Psych::DisallowedClass exception when using YAML.load_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332602/upgrading-to-ruby-3-1-causes-psychdisallowedclass-exception-when-using-yaml-lo)

As a temporary workaround, I've rolled back to `6.1.6` Rails version but I'm looking for a proper solution to this issue.

Comment: For me adding `config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date, Time, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone]` in `config/application.rb ` solved the issue. Did you restart the server after changing this config file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following to the file `config/application.rb`.

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date, Time, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone]
```

It should solve the issue. Then restart the server and `reload!` the Rails console to ensure it works.

Credit to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312283/tried-to-load-unspecified-class-activesupporttimewithzone-psychdisallowed/75895483#comment133344484_74312283) above for providing this solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @huertanix 

What else did you try? Is there any other error information surrounding your error? Did the error change after updating your config? Did you restart the rails server? What are your ruby and rails versions?

Comment: I am getting this error for Date class Psych::DisallowedClass: Tried to load unspecified class: Date,  I tried this but its not solving my issue.

Comment: Using Rails 6.0.6.1 with Ruby 3.0.2. Tried adding this to the three environment configs too, but that did nothing.

Also tried tenderlove's `config.active_record.use_yaml_unsafe_load` option, which is not a great idea security-wise, but that didn't work either.

Naturally restarted my rails web server so many times. Even rebooting my whole machine just to completely rule out the possibility.

Ended up changing my fixtures' Date fields to Strings by putting their values in quotes. It's inelegant, tedious, but that seems to be the vibe with this framework.

Comment: that worked for me, just had to add more classes to the list! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Also, ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess, BigDecimal has issues. Please add. if you have any trouble.

config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol, Date, Time, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone, ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess, BigDecimal]
```