# Rails Admin gem throwing Psych::DisallowedClass error when editing blob record. Any solutions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [rails admin gem](https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin) for editing creating records etc. There is a section which contains blobs part. When I tried to edit a blob record (not editing any field just pressing save) causes:

`Psych::DisallowedClass: Tried to load unspecified class: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`

[image: rails admin example]

[Upgrading to Ruby 3.1 causes Psych::DisallowedClass exception when using YAML.load_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332602/upgrading-to-ruby-3-1-causes-psychdisallowedclass-exception-when-using-yaml-lo) I tried method in this thread but no luck.

versions:

- Rails 5.2.8.1
- activestorage (5.2.8.1)
- rails_admin (2.2.1)

Any suggestions? Thanks.